# Will using "Jeep" as a character name cause copyright issues?

Tags: copyright, naming, videogame

As the title says I have a character named "Jeep" and I would like to know if it will cause any copyright problems for me or not.

(P.S: By the way, it's for a script for a game.)

Comment: Unless your character is a car, I think it should be fine. Companies cannot copyright individual words.

Comment: There's always ["Eugene the Jeep"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_the_Jeep) as a character in Popeye comic strips and cartoons.  Eugene the Jeep actually pre-dates the Army vehicle and the civilian vehicles that came after the war.

Comment: oh, thanks everyone!

Comment: @JRE If I recall, Eugene the Jeep actually inspired the Jeep company's name.

Comment: @hszmv:  Nope.  Jeeps (the Army vehicle) was originally built by Willys-Overland.  It was called a "General Purpose" vehicle,  abbreviated as "GP."  Soldiers took to calling it a "jeep," but it isn't clear if that came by way of pronouncing "GP" as a word or by connection to Eugene - or both.  Willys trademarked the vehicle name "Jeep" around 1950 and sold vehicle models under that name.   Take a look at the [Wikipedia page for "Jeep."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeep)   It has a good bit about the history of the Jeep.

Comment: Same article does lend support and it was backed up by R. Lee Ermey in Mail Call.  Not gonna call bullshit on a drill sergeant who very likely is calling the Armies of God "Maggots" at this very moment.

Comment: The name Jeep is trademarked. There is a doctrine of fair use, but it's different for trademarks than copyright.

Comment: One of the characters in David Brin's The Postman was named Ford Lincoln Mercury, so there is precedence on your side.  I would suggest that you make the character noble with high-character and physical attributes, as Brin did.  If your Jeep is fumble footed or lazy, it might be seen as an oblique insult to the company or its products.  Keep in mind, major companies keep lawyers on staff to handle just such offenses.

Comment: @HenryTaylor Not to mention Ford Prefect from *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*, who explicitly named himself after the car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copyright does not protect single words or short phrases, such as book or film titles. Trademark law can, but there are limitations.

A trademark only protects a name used in trade, that is used to sell or advertise something, or indicate the source of something being sold or promoted for sale. It protects against someone else using the same mark, or a confusingly similar mark, to sell or identify a similar sort of product or service.  Thus, using "Jeep" to label any kind of automobile would probably infringe the famous mark owned by the Jeep company (formerly Willys-Overland). Using it as a name for a character in a novel would not so infringe.

If a use might plausibly lead a reasonable person to think that a product or service is sponsored, endorsed, or approved by the trademark holder when it is not, that would  also be trademark infringement. This does not seem to apply to the situation in the question.

A trademark can be used without permission to refer to the trademarked product or company, but this also doesn't seem to apply here.

In short, no legal problem seems likely from the situation described in the question.

In future, one might get better answers, or quicker ones, to this sort of question on Law SE, where trademark issues are addressed with some frequency.

Comment: Just don't use it in the title of the story. Since the title would be used in advertising, they could attempt a trademark suit based on that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. The word "jeep" is a common noun for a 4x4 vehicle in many languages, including English. As far as I know, it was trademarked well after it came into general use during WW2.